# Windows Service Logon Failure - No Network Avaliable

Tags: windows-services, authentication

I developed a windows service that must logon to a server. It works fine. I set it to start automatically when the windows starts.

The problem is when there is no network avaliable, generating a "logon failure". This service MUST run 24hours a day, 365 days a year.

How can I avoid this service from crashing when it trys to logon, but can't reach the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `try...catch` block, and set up a timer for say 30 seconds to retry.

Comment: But where should this try/catch block be? Would it be something like try {ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);} catch {Thread.Sleep(30000);}?

Comment: It should surround the network access code. But no Thread.Sleep, but a Timer instead.

Comment: That is exactly the problem; there is no network access code. The service starts with a network user (domain), instead of a local user. So, when the service starts, it trys to logon, but crashs if there is no network access.

Comment: Can it be changed to start with 'Local Service' account?

Comment: Nop, it must start with a network user, so it can access and manipulate shared folders.